# HTTPS load other website content

Tags: iis

On my windows 2003 server I have two websites: 2send.co.il & oferavnir.co.il

For 2send.co.il I installed SSL.

When I adding Https to oferavnir.co.il (the site without the SSL) the other site content is displayed -

(https://oferavnir.co.il displays the content from 2send.co.il)

Host headers for both site seems to be ok.

What could it be?

Comment: what could be the problem? why when I am using https I am getting the other site content?

Comment: it's not the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SSL certificate is probably bound to all IP addresses on your server. If you have individual IPs for each site, you can update the binding to only listen on the IP for 2send.co.il. If you are using host headers and a single IP, the 2send.co.il site will respond for all https requests. You could use a product like ISAPI Rewrite to check the URL used for an HTTPS request and ensure that it matches 2send.co.il or else route it to the appropriate http site for the URL

http://forums.iis.net/t/1195794.aspx/1?HTTPS+displays+other+site+contnet

Comment: You said it was not the bindings?